# Angular = getting invalid array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ceil

I have the following function in my controller...

```
$scope.pagerPages = function (n) {
    var i = Math.ceil(n);
    return new Array(i);
}
```

the `n` comes from an expression on the view, and can sometimes be a fraction. Which is why I've done `Math.ceil` on `n`.

Anyone know why I would be getting this error?

> Invalid array length

EDIT;
`n` is a calculation from the view

```
<div ng-repeat="i in pagerPages( report.TotalNumRows / report.View.PageSize ) track by $index">
...
</div>
```

the calculation results in 11.2, which is evidentally working, as on the page i get 12 iterations of the div element, yet it's generating this error?

Comment: what is the value of `i` when you get the error?

Comment: More importantly, what is `n` *exactly*?

Comment: Can `n` have negative values?

Comment: Did you fix this issue?  I am testing code that has the same problem.

Comment: i had completely forgotten about this, yes, i discovered that the issue was a negative number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of `i`. I suspect it's negative

Even if `n` was a string or an object it would still work. You'd only get that error is `i` is a negative number.

i.e. `new Array({})` or `new Array('ergerg')` wont give you an error, but `new Array(-2)` will give you the error you have